# Aplicação com Spring + BootStrap com problema para localizar o contextPath e aplicar os CSS

Tags: java, spring, bootstrap, spring-mvc

A página está funcionando normalmente, porém o CSS não está sendo aplicado, assim como, imagens dentro do resources não estão sendo localizadas. Segue metodos da classe de configuração para localizar resources, e nem assim funciona.

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

Página:

```
<c:url value="/resources/css" var="cssPath" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${cssPath }/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${cssPath }/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Livros de java, Android, Iphone, PHP, Ruby e muito mais - Casa do código</title>


<c:url value="/resources/css" var="cssPath" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->


<style type="text/css">
    body{
            padding: 0px 30px;
    }
</style>


</head>
<body>


    <h1>Cadastro de Jidoka</h1>
    <form:form action="${s:mvcUrl('CC#gravarJidoka').build() }" method="post" commandName="jidoka" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Título</label>
            <form:input path="titulo" cssClass="form-control" />
            <form:errors path="titulo" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Descrição</label>
            <form:textarea path="descricao" cssClass="form-control" />
            <form:errors path="descricao" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Solicitante</label>
            <form:input path="solicitante" cssClass="form-control"/>
            <form:errors path="solicitante" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Setor Solicitante</label>
            <form:input path="setorSolicitante" cssClass="form-control" />
            <form:errors path="setorSolicitante" />
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Classe:

```
package br.com.schmersal.chamadostv.conf;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.guava.GuavaCacheManager;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.format.datetime.DateFormatter;
import org.springframework.format.datetime.DateFormatterRegistrar;
import org.springframework.format.support.DefaultFormattingConversionService;
import org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder;

import br.com.schmersal.chamadostv.controllers.ChamadosController;
import br.com.schmersal.chamadostv.daos.ProdutoDao;

@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { ChamadosController.class, ProdutoDao.class })
@EnableCaching
public class AppWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolve() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolve = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolve.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolve.setSuffix(".jsp");

        // resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true); poder pegar
        // qualquer variavel
        resolve.setExposedContextBeanNames("carrinhoCompras");
        return resolve;

    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {

        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

        messageSource.setBasename("/WEB-INF/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(1);

        return messageSource;

    }

    @Bean
    public FormattingConversionService mvcConversionService() {
        DefaultFormattingConversionService conversionService = new DefaultFormattingConversionService();
        DateFormatterRegistrar registra = new DateFormatterRegistrar();
        registra.setFormatter(new DateFormatter("dd/MM/yyyy"));
        registra.registerFormatters(conversionService);

        return conversionService;

    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        CacheBuilder<Object, Object> builder = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(100).expireAfterAccess(1,
                TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        GuavaCacheManager manager = new GuavaCacheManager();
        manager.setCacheBuilder(builder);
        return manager;
    }

    // @Bean
    // public ViewResolver
    // contentNegotiationViewResolver(ContentNegotiationManager manager) {
    // List<ViewResolver> viewResolvers = new ArrayList<>();
    // viewResolvers.add(internalResourceViewResolve());
    // viewResolvers.add(new JsonViewResolver());
    // ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new
    // ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
    // resolver.setViewResolvers(viewResolvers);
    // resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);
    // return resolver;
    // }

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Coloque classpath: para que o spring encontre os recursos

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/");
}
```

Para carregar no HTML

```
<link href="/resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/resources/js/general.js"></script>
```

Comment: Infelizmente ainda não resolveu, continua dando 404 no console (f12 no navegador aba network) e esta buscando no seguinte local: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: Poste a classe completa com o código assim e também o HTML que importa os recursos

Comment: Enviei tudo Marquezani

Comment: Realizei a criação do projeto novamente usando o jboss forge e copiei classes e jsp.. e o resto manteve o msm